# VBA: Two methods of seeing if a file is open

Tags: vba, excel, file-io

I've got two methods which I feel should tell if a file is open or not.

**Method 1** (Error: Subscript out of range):

```
If Not Workbooks(filename) Is Nothing Then
    Workbooks.Open (filename)
End If
```

**Method 2**:

```
If Not IsWorkbookOpen(filename) Then
    Workbooks.Open (filename)
End If
```

Where `IsWorkbookOpen()` is:

```
Private Function IsWorkbookOpen(wbname) As Boolean

Dim wBook As Workbook
Set wBook = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Set wBook = Workbooks(wbname)

If wBook Is Nothing Then
    IsWorkbookOpen = False
    Else: IsWorkbookOpen = True
End If

End Function
```

Aside from `On Error Resume Next`, **Method 1** appears to be nearly the same as **Method 2**.

Could anyone please explain why **Method 1** gives the error it does?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

They both give a subscript out of range error. But in Method 2 you suppress that error with `On Error Resume Next`.

```
Sub SeeError()

    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print Workbooks("DoesNotExist").Name

    Debug.Print Err.Description

End Sub
```

This prints "Subscript Out of Range" in the Immediate Window. The On Error statement doesn't stop the error from occurring, it just handles it. Method 1 doesn't handle errors so the default error handling (stop execution and report the error) is in effect.

Answer (score 1):

VBA tries to evaluate all the parts before it evaluates the conditional statement. So if I have a variable `myvar = "xyz"` and try to run the following lines...

```
If IsNumeric(myvar) And Round(myvar, 1) = 3 Then
    'you will get an error before the IF is evaluated
End If
```

it will not work. VBA will evaluate `IsNumeric(myvar)` fine, then try to evaluate `Round(myvar, 1) = 3` and get an error before it checks the entire conditional. So VBA will let you know about the error before it performs the `AND` operator. If VBA had [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), it would work fine since the first part would evaluate to false.

But the following will work

```
If IsNumeric(myvar) Then
    If Round(myvar, 1) = 3 Then
        'second IF statement is not touched since first IF statement evaluates to false
    End If
End If
```

This works because `IsNumeric(myvar)` evaluates to false and therefore skips the nested statement.

So the error it throws on the `Workbooks(filename)` will just give the error unless you tell it to resume next. So the method I use is

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(file)
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(dir & "\" & file, ReadOnly:=True)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Edited to give more detail and correctly capture that the second example will not be evaluated as well as provide a useful solution for the question at hand.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Why are your two exmaples different? I also think you meant to use myvar in your declaration, not simply var.

Comment: I edited my post to add more detail. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thank you! Now I believe understand what you are saying, but I'm confused about debug.print "will show". My understanding of both the code and your explanation is that that text will never be displayed.

Comment: You are correct.I had `debug.print` just so i could test it and make sure it works, but hopefully the commented lines make it more clear.

Comment: Much clearer, thank you. I didn't want to edit since I wasn't initially sure of your meaning, and did not want to mince your words. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Workbooks(filename)` tries to get the element with the identifier (or 'index') `filename` from the collection `Workbooks`. If the collection does not contain such an element, you'll get the "Subscript out of range" error. (So in a nutshell: This code will fail whenever the file is not open. You probably don't want this.)

However, the knowledge that such an access will fail if the file is not open, i.e. an error is raised, is being made use of in the second method. The code tries to get the element with the identifier `filename` from the `Workbooks` collection and to assign it to the variable `wBook`. If it fails, the value of the variable `wBook` will stay `Nothing`. If it succeeds, the variable `wBook` will contain a reference to the respective Workbook object.